# The definitive "how to travel with multiple passports" Q&A

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

We get [a lot of questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dual-nationality) about "I have passports X and Y, how do I travel from A to B", and while the combinations are near-infinite, the basic answers boil down into a few possible scenarios.

[Joel Spolsky's answer to this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/travelling-with-two-different-passports) is justly highly rated, but has not been anointed as the accepted answer and doesn't show up top.  Also, while it mentions the common scenario where the traveler is hiding X's citizenship from Y, it doesn't offer suggestions for how to work around this.

**Should we create a generic question with a definitive answer?**

Comment: I will answer in a comment.  I vote that you CONTRIVE a generic question making no secret that it is canonical.  Put a bounty on it.  Put your own answer in and let it sink or swim alongside organic answers.  At the end, wikifie the right answer and come to meta and tell us what type of questions we should dup vote.  I agree to dup vote in line

Comment: First shot at canonical Q&A written:

**http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel/52101#52101**

Comment: +1, I like it; there's a use case to be added but that's for later.  Right now I am asking myself 'how do I find it after about two months from now'?

Comment: Can I add another answer, with a graphic flowchart, for the special case of US/UK duals?  Even though it is covered in the abstract by your answer?

Comment: @GayotFow Happy to community wiki the answer if you think your edits would be useful to all, but what's special about US/UK duals?

Comment: @GayotFow About to head out, but I've wikied the answer, edit away.

Comment: There is no defect in your answer, and nothing particularly special about US/UK duals other than my comment above ('abstract'). After looking at it, I cannot edit the wiki answer for the special case. Instead, I have mounted a graphic on my wordpress blog.  You can inspect it there and see if it's of any use.  Again, no defects found in your answer and I'm grateful to you for having wiki'fied it.

Comment: @GayotFow Got link?

Comment: Please see https://gayotfow.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/croppercapture4.jpg remembering that it does not corrrect anything in your answer. It's for those less able to follow the algebraic representation in the canonical answer.

Answer (score 4):

I agree there is an underlying ‘theme” to the various scenarios as I think they all render down to little more than a single factor. Basically “*is the person currently to inspect the passport responsible for Immigration*?”. If `yes` show them the one *they* want to see, if `no` show them the one (or both) *you* want them to see.

Perhaps a little more complex, given say a visa in one passport and a name that matches a booking in another, but that’s the sort of situation a canonical answer would cover.

I think generalization might help to extract the relevant considerations from an element of extraneous ones usually connected with a set of specific circumstances. Also that a few, perhaps colour-coded, diagrams would aid clarification while unlikely ever to be provided for the non-routine conditions that would have to be present for any further "two-passport" question to avoid being a duplicate.

What concerns me slightly is the *we* in “we create”. I have seen many good ideas proposed on metas that have not been carried through (but more on SO than TSE). I am not sure that advocating some work for someone when I don’t intend that ‘someone’ to be me is entirely appropriate.

In general, of course we want canonical answers – there should be no need to ask *that*! But if asking anyway is an implied request for assistance I don’t wish my agreement to imply much by way of practical support, in the matter of dual nationality.

Incidentally, I say ‘dual nationality’ rather than ‘multiple passports’ because I do not have dual nationality (hence not well *qualified* to help) but do have more than one passport. That raises issues but I think not ones that should be covered by the proposal above.

Comment: For clarity, I'm volunteering to write the initial Q&A, and community wiki it if that seems useful.